# How does `sqrt` behaves for negative values in GLSL?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl

I have been wondering if `sqrt(num)` is equal to `sqrt(abs(num))` in GLSL. This exactly how this function is behaving in [this shader](http://glslsandbox.com/e#20618.1). I am not able to find any docs or references on this behaviour. In this shader a unit circle is formed and value inside `sqrt` is negative for outside pixels of circle, But results are as if `abs` has been takent before applying `sqrt`.

Comment: probably implementation defined

Answer (score 7, accepted):

according to [the spec](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/sqrt.xhtml)

> sqrt returns the square root of x. i.e., the value √x. **Results are undefined** if x<0.

Which means anything can happen, but some implementations would just ignore the sign bit on the argument and return a positive number.

Comment: yeah I read the docs but i was wondering if I am missing something. Thanks anyways !

Answer (score 0):

[Docs](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/sqrt.xhtml) answer those types of question:

> Results are undefined if x<0.